# Type based tag dispatching: Is it possible to differently tag containers based on the tags of their elements?

Tags: c++, templates, type-traits

Pleases disregard the row of warnings because of unused variables, the algorithms are dummy example functions.

Also, sorry for the lengthy post, I tried to shorten it as much as possible.

The following tag types and the tag structure are given:

```
namespace tags {

    struct ordinary_tag{}; 
    struct special_tag {}; 
    struct extra_special_tag {};

    struct ordinary_collection_tag {}; 
    struct special_collection_tag {}; 

    template<typename Type>
    struct tag 
    {
        typedef void type; 
    }; 

}
```

and the concrete classes used for algorithm arguments:

```
class concrete_one {}; 
class concrete_two {};
```

The `implementation` namespace stores implementations of an algorithm `algorithm`, based on the *type of the algorithm result*, which can be any type, that is tagged with a specific tag. The tag of the results determines the algorithm chosen:

```
namespace implementation {

template<typename Result, typename Tag>
struct algorithm {};

template<typename Result> 
struct algorithm<Result, tags::ordinary_tag>
{
    static Result apply(concrete_one const & a1, concrete_two const & a2)
    {
        Result r; 

        std::cout << "ordinary" << std::endl;
        // Modify r using a1, a2. 

        return r; 
    } 

    // Commutative algorithm. 
    static Result apply(concrete_two const & a1, concrete_one const & a2)
    {
        return apply(a2, a1); 
    }
};

template<typename Result> 
struct algorithm<Result, tags::special_tag>
{
    static Result apply(concrete_one const & a1, concrete_two const & a2)
    {
        Result r; 

        std::cout << "special" << std::endl;
        // Modify r using a1, a2.

        return r; 
    } 
};
...
```

and the algorithms are also tagged for collections of tagged element types, like for example when the Result is tagged as a collection of ordinary types:

```
template<typename Result>
struct algorithm<Result, tags::ordinary_collection_tag>
{
    static Result apply(concrete_one const & a1, concrete_two const & a2)
    {
        Result r; 

        std::cout << "ordinary collection" << std::endl;

        // Modify r using a1, a2.

        return r; 
    } 
};
```

The algorithms from the `implementation` namespace are dispatched by a function template that uses variadic arguments:

```
template<typename Result, typename ... Arguments>
Result algorithm(Arguments ... args)
{
    // Dispatch to the appropriate algorithm based on the result tag
    // and overload within the algorithm structure for the variadic arguments
    return implementation::algorithm<Result, typename tags::tag<Result>::type>::apply(args ...);
}
```

Some types are defined and tagged differently:

```
struct first_type {}; 

namespace tags {
    // Make first_type behave as ordinary type.
    template<>
    struct tag<first_type>
    {
        typedef ordinary_tag type; 
    };
}

struct second_type {};  

namespace tags {
    // Make second_type behave as a special type.
    template<>
    struct tag<second_type>
    {
        typedef special_tag type; 
    };
}
```

and they work perfectly fine as expected:

```
concrete_one c1; 
concrete_two c2; 

first_type f1 = algorithm<first_type>(c1, c2); 

second_type f2 = algorithm<second_type>(c1, c2);
```

but the problem is in a specialization of `tag` to take into account any container with an allocator, and tag it based on the tag of the container element type. This is what I have tried to do:

```
namespace tags 
{
    // An attempt to tag all Containers with Allocator of ordinary tagged types using ordinary_collection_tag.
    template 
    <
        typename OrdinaryType,  
        template <typename, typename> class Container, 
        template <typename> class Allocator 
    >
    struct tag
    <
        typename std::enable_if 
        <
            std::is_same<typename tags::tag<OrdinaryType>::type, tags::ordinary_tag>::value, // true if OrdinaryType is tagged with ordinary_tag
            Container<OrdinaryType, Allocator<OrdinaryType>> // Use this as the T argument of enable_if
        >::type // in enable_if specialized for "true" :: typename T type; 
    > 
    {
        typedef ordinary_collection_tag type; 
    };
}
```

Expecting that `enable_if` will provide as it's `T` argument the `Container<OrdinaryType, Allocator<OrdinaryType>>` if the human-named `OrdinaryType` really is tagged with `ordinary_tag` - this is the boolean argument to `enable_if` that should be provided by `is_same`. I tried to use the STL containers that hold the `first_type` tagged as ordinary in the following way:

```
    typedef std::list<first_type> first_type_list; 
    typedef std::vector<first_type> first_type_vector; 

    first_type_list fl = algorithm<first_type_list>(c1, c2); 
    first_type_vector fv = algorithm<first_type_vector>(c1, c2);
```

Instead of recognizing `first_type_list/vector` as `ordinary_collection_tag`-ed types, I get the following error:

```
test-other.cpp:158:12: error: template parameters not used in partial specialization:
     struct tag
test-other.cpp:158:12: error:         ‘OrdinaryType’
test-other.cpp:158:12: error:         ‘template<class, class> class Container’
test-other.cpp:158:12: error:         ‘template<class> class Allocator’
```

Now, when I don't enable the `tag` specialization based on the tag of the `OrdinaryType`, and I specialize it for any `OrdinaryType` like this:

```
// Works but doesn't see that OrdinaryType should be tagged with ordinary_tag, 
// std::list<first_type> and std::vector<second_type> are both tagged ordinary_collection_tag. 
//namespace tags 
//{
    //template 
    //<
        //typename OrdinaryType,  
        //template <typename, typename> class Container, 
        //template <typename> class Allocator 
    //>
    //struct tag
    //<
        //Container<OrdinaryType, Allocator<OrdinaryType>>
    //> 
    //{
        //typedef ordinary_collection_tag type; 
    //};
//};
```

then types like `std::vector<first_type>` and `std::list<second_type>` get both tagged with `ordinary_collection_tag` even though `second_type` is tagged with the `special_tag`. This is what I have expected.

So, what did I do wrong?

I'm using gcc 4.8.2.

The complete small program can be found [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/808ff0547f854c78).

Comment: Compiler produces quite accurate diagnosis: such 'specialization' of `struct tag` does not really uses its template parameters.

Comment: @Constructor, yep, this is what I figured, but the question still remains: how do I specialize `tag` for all containers that hold tagged elements? Right now I'm trying to do that using `value_type`, and counting on the template deduction mechanism, but I'm still failing..

Answer (score 2):

Since no one answered yet and I have found a possible solution to the problem, I've decided to post it.

Instead of trying to partially specialize `tag` for any container like I did in the question, I assumed that having a container of elements is a general case. As a result, the `tag<Type>` template expexts `Type` to be a collection. If `Type` does not satisfy this condition, the template deduction chooses another specialization of `Type` that fits: the one for a single element. The condition is imposed by introducing a `collection` structure. Any container that has `value_type` available is now recognized as a collection of tagged elements.

Here is the solution (I just changed the names of types into fruit names, I guess to make it more easy to read):

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

namespace tags {

    struct apple_tag {}; 
    struct banana_tag {}; 

    struct apple_collection_tag {}; 
    struct banana_collection_tag {}; 

    template<typename Tag>
    struct collection {}; 

    template<>
    struct collection<apple_tag>
    {
        typedef apple_collection_tag type; 
    };

    template<>
    struct collection<banana_tag>
    {
        typedef banana_collection_tag type; 
    };


    template<typename Type>
    struct tag 
    {
        typedef typename collection<typename tag<typename Type::value_type>::type>::type type; 
    }; 

    // Select tags of pairs based on the second type. Used for maps (key, value) pairs.   
    template
    <
        typename First,
        typename Second 
    >
    struct tag<std::pair<First, Second>>
    {
        typedef typename tag<Second>::type type; 
    };
}

struct apple {}; 

namespace tags {
    template<>
    struct tag<apple>
    {
        typedef apple_tag type; 
    };
}

struct banana {}; 

namespace tags {
    template<>
    struct tag<banana>
    {
        typedef banana_tag type; 
    };
}

template<typename Type> 
struct my_container
{
    typedef Type value_type; 
};

namespace implementation {

    template<typename Type, typename Tag>
    struct function {}; 

    template<typename Type>
    struct function<Type, tags::apple_tag> 
    {
        static void apply(Type const& t)
        {
            std::cout << "apple" << std::endl;
        }
    };

    template<typename Type>
    struct function<Type, tags::banana_tag> 
    {
        static void apply(Type const& t)
        {
            std::cout << "banana" << std::endl;
        }
    };

    template<typename Type>
    struct function<Type, tags::apple_collection_tag> 
    {
        static void apply(Type const& t)
        {
            std::cout << "apple collection" << std::endl;
        }
    };

    template<typename Type>
    struct function<Type, tags::banana_collection_tag> 
    {
        static void apply(Type const& t)
        {
            std::cout << "banana collection" << std::endl;
        }
    };
}

// Value tag Dispatcher
template<typename Type>
void function(Type const & t)
{
    implementation::function<Type, typename tags::tag<Type>::type>::apply(t); 
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    typedef std::list<apple> apple_bag; 

    apple_bag abag; 

    function(abag); 

    typedef std::vector<apple> apple_box; 

    apple_box abox; 

    function(abox); 

    typedef std::map<int, apple> apple_orchard; 

    apple_orchard ao; 

    function (ao);

    // my_container has value_type, so it can be used as well. 
    typedef my_container<banana> banana_bag; 

    banana_bag bo; 

    function(bo); 

    return 0;
}
```

That's it. Here's the output:

```
apple collection
apple collection
apple collection
banana collection
```